# requestIdleCallback vs promise

Tags: javascript, browser

I've just found out about `window.requestIdleCallback` and I am wondering on the difference with just a plain promise.

As far as I know JS is already good at queuing promises, so I do not see any benefit unless `requestIdleCallback` uses a different queue with lower priority. In that case I would assume it is great because I would like having a way to make clear which code has lower priority than rendering.

Comment: Where did you find out about `requestIdleCallback` and what made you assume that it is comparable to promises, especially wrt. priority?

Comment: `requestIdleCallback` has a **far** lower priority than promise microtasks. Not sure what you mean by "*JS is already good at queuing promises*".

Comment: @Bergi arguably Promises aren't part of any priority system at all, they are queued then dequeued ASAP.

Comment: @Kaiido I guess ASAP amounts to "highest priority", no? :D But I can see where you're coming from.

Comment: @Bergi they are comparable in that they both end up in the event event loop. The question was to confirm if they are handled in a different way there, specially their priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.requestIdleCallback` simply runs the function during the browser idle periods to avoid impacting animations and input responses etc.

Promises are just a way of using asynchronous code. That code may be run while the browser is not idle (if the promise is not pending), and could possibly impact latency critical events.

Therefore, promises may or may not run during the browser idle period, but the `requestIdleCallback` will always run in the idle period (assuming the timeout isn't exceeded).

Please note, these 2 concepts are not interchangeable. Yes, you can run asynchronous "promise" code within the `requestIdleCallback`, but the callback should not be used to replace the functionality of a promise. That is, you shouldn't replace the use of promises with the callback, but use them together if appropriate.

Here's some info about `window.requestIdleCallback`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback

And Promises here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: "*Please note, these 2 concepts…*" - what are you quoting there? I can't find that text in either of the two pages you linked.

Comment: Good attempt at answering such a question. I just have a small remark on the "and could possibly impact latency critical events", which makes it sound like rIC's callback wouldn't impact perfs. So to make it clear, the callback also does block the event loop like any other callback and task, only the schedule is set to when the browser is idle.